# What is the name of this cache design pattern?

Tags: caching, design-patterns

We have a system where the results of expensive database queries + business logic are cached to reduce latency for subsequent requests. Multiple hosts handle requests and use a shared cache. In the ['cache-aside' pattern](https://blog.cdemi.io/design-patterns-cache-aside-pattern/), the request flow is:

1. Determine whether the item is currently held in the cache
2. If the item is not currently in the cache, read the item from the data store
3. Store a copy of the item in the cache

Because our queries and business logic are expensive, several thousand requests for the item can occur between steps 1 and 3, each triggering step two, overloading the data store. We use a pattern we dub the *pending* or the *sentinel*:

1. Determine whether the item is currently held in the cache and atomically store a 'result pending' object (sentinel) if it is missing
2. If the item is not currently in the cache, read the item from the data store; if the item in the cache is the sentinel, back off and retry the operation until a result arrives or timeout (in which case, restart the operation)
3. Store a copy of the item in the cache, replacing the sentinel value and effectively 'unblocking' requests trying to read the value

I can't find any examples or discussion of this in the literature, is there a name or any reference for this pattern?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but the _problem_ you are describing is also known as a Cache Stampede. The pattern you describe sounds a bit like a mutex or lock to me.

Comment: Sometimes referred to as memoization, but the exact strategies to cache stampedes are varied, like [probabilistic expiration](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~avattani/papers/cache_stampede.pdf).

Comment: That sounds like a type of [isolation scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)) to me; possibly a *serializable read*.

Comment: The Wikipedia article for [Cache Stampede](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_stampede#Cache_stampede_mitigation) refers to this solution as Locking.

Comment: This is an interesting problem. If the cache server could reliably approximate the database query time, a combination of the 1st two bullet points in the Locking approach in the Wikipedia Cache Stampede article would likely work pretty well.